Бот выводит всего 1 results в InlineQueryResultArticle вместо 2
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить код, чтобы в inline mode при вводе ключевого слова выводилось не 1 наименование, а сразу все упоминания по таблице? Ошибка в id='2',но что-то не могу разобраться, какой ID вводить
@dp.inline_handler(lambda query: len(query.query) > 0)
async def inline_handler(query: types.InlineQuery):
    ID = str(query.from_user.id)
    text = query.query
    text = text.upper()
    file = "Trello/Trello.xlsx"
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, read_only=False)
    ws = wb[ID]

    for row in ws.iter_rows(1):
        for cell in row:
            if re.findall(text, str(cell.value).upper()):
                satus = ws.cell(column=3, row=cell.row).value
                name = ws.cell(column=2, row=cell.row).value

                articles = [types.InlineQueryResultArticle(
                    id='2',
                    title=name,
                    description=satus,
                    input_message_content=types.InputTextMessageContent(message_text=name))]

                await query.answer(articles, cache_time=5, is_personal=True)

В таблице 2 строки со словом "Инжир"

Но бот выводит только 1


Получилось через append

@dp.inline_handler(lambda query: len(query.query) > 0)
async def inline_handler(query: types.InlineQuery):
    ID = str(query.from_user.id)
    text = query.query
    text = text.upper()
    file = "Trello/Trello.xlsx"
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, read_only=False)
    ws = wb[ID]

    list = []
    list_2 = []

    for row in ws.iter_rows(1):
        for cell in row:
            if re.findall(text, str(cell.value).upper()):
                satus = ws.cell(column=3, row=cell.row).value
                name = ws.cell(column=2, row=cell.row).value
                list.append([satus])
                list_2.append([name])

    articles = []
    for i in range(len(list_2)):
        articles.append(types.InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=str(i),
            title=str((str(list_2[i])).replace("['", '')).replace("']", ''),
            description=str((str(list[i])).replace("['", '')).replace("']", ''),
            input_message_content=types.InputTextMessageContent(
                message_text=str((str(list_2[i])).replace("['", '')).replace("']", ''))))

    await query.answer(articles, cache_time=0, is_personal=True)

